# AndEngine: Rotation Modifier not working visually in MultiTouch for second finger

Tags: android, andengine

I have two sliders in my game , which rotate and scale+position the player sprite respectively.

Left slider rotate the sprite
and the right scale + move the player with some velocity

I have included the MultiTouch extension

The problem is that;

When i touch the left slider first ( rotate first) and then the second i.e. the right slider, everything works perfectly.
However when i touch the right slider first, and then the left ,rotation happens, but rotation is not seen visually.

What can be the issue?
If required ill share the code

**ROTATION SLIDER CODE FOR ONAREATOUCHED**

```
    @Override
   public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent touchEvent,float pTouchAreaLocalX,float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

        mPlayer.clearRotationModifiers();
        float currentRotationValue;

        if(touchEvent.isActionDown())
        {

            //gesture detector enabled for rotation slider only
            mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(touchEvent.getMotionEvent());

            this.LastPositionTouched=touchEvent.getMotionEvent().getY();
            currentRotationValue=this.CalculateCurrentCalibratedValue(pTouchAreaLocalY);



            mPlayer.MakeRotation(currentRotationValue);
            mPlayer.pressedPlayerActionOnRotation=1; //press started
        }
        if( touchEvent.isActionMove() )
        {


            this.DistanceConveredSinceLastDownEvent=touchEvent.getMotionEvent().getY()-this.LastPositionTouched;

            if( Math.abs(this.DistanceConveredSinceLastDownEvent) > HUDBar.minScrollDistanceCovered ){

                    mPlayer.pressedPlayerActionOnRotation=1;
                    currentRotationValue=this.CalculateCurrentCalibratedValue(pTouchAreaLocalY);                                
                    mPlayer.MakeRotation(currentRotationValue);
                }
            this.LastPositionTouched=touchEvent.getMotionEvent().getY();

        }
        if(touchEvent.isActionUp())
        {
            this.LastPositionTouched=0;
            MainActivity.this.mPlayer.pressedPlayerActionOnRotation=0; //pressing stopped
            mPlayer.resetRotation(-90); 
            //----reset debug variables-----
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

**DepthSlider code**

```
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent touchEvent,float pTouchAreaLocalX,float pTouchAreaLocalY)
    {


        float ScaleValue,StringLengthFactor,SpeedFactor;

        //mPlayer.clearEntityModifiers();

        if(touchEvent.isActionDown())
        {

            //for implementing custom longpress
            this.isActionDownOccured=true;
            //mPlayer.pressedTime=touchEvent.getMotionEvent().getEventTime();
            this.initialTime=touchEvent.getMotionEvent().getDownTime();
            this.pressedTime=this.initialTime;

            /////////////////////////////////////////////       
            this.LastPositionTouched=touchEvent.getY();
            //gesturedetector onDown motionevent passed in onLongPress
        //  mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(touchEvent.getMotionEvent());

            ScaleValue=this.CalculateCurrentCalibratedValue(pTouchAreaLocalY);                  
            StringLengthFactor =   ScaleValue * ScaleToStringLengthConversionFactor;
            SpeedFactor        =  (ScaleValue>0) ? ScaleValue * ScaleToSpeedConversionFactor:0;


            //---display local variables before set speed----------------
            /*MainActivity.this.txtLoggingSpriteVariables.setText( 
                    "TouchAreaLocalY: "+Float.toString(pTouchAreaLocalY)+
                    "  Speed From:"+
                    Float.toString(MainActivity.this.mPlayer.getSpeed())+
                    " to: "+ Integer.toString(currentSpeedValue) 
                    );
            */

            mPlayer.setSpeedAndScaleInParallel(SpeedFactor, ScaleValue);
            mPlayer.setDeltaStringLength(StringLengthFactor);

            MainActivity.this.txtDepthLogger.setText("DepthSlider Down Event"+(MainActivity.this.MoveEventDepthSliderCount++)+"\n"+
                     "PointerCount "+touchEvent.getMotionEvent().getPointerCount()+" New Scale:"  + mPlayer.getScaleX()+" \n " +
                     " New Speed: "+ mPlayer.getSpeed()
                    );

            MainActivity.this.mPlayer.pressedPlayerActionOnDepth=1; //depth slider pressed
        }
        if(touchEvent.isActionMove())
        {

            this.DistanceConveredSinceLastDownEvent=touchEvent.getY()-this.LastPositionTouched;

            if( Math.abs(this.DistanceConveredSinceLastDownEvent) > HUDBar.minScrollDistanceCovered ) {

                ScaleValue=this.CalculateCurrentCalibratedValue(pTouchAreaLocalY);                  
                StringLengthFactor =   ScaleValue * ScaleToStringLengthConversionFactor;
                SpeedFactor        =  (ScaleValue>0) ? ScaleValue * ScaleToSpeedConversionFactor:0;

                MainActivity.this.mPlayer.setSpeedAndScaleInParallel(SpeedFactor, ScaleValue);
                MainActivity.this.mPlayer.setDeltaStringLength(StringLengthFactor);

                //reset LongPress variables

                mPlayer.pressedPlayerActionOnDepth=1;
                this.initialTime=touchEvent.getMotionEvent().getEventTime();
                this.pressedTime=this.initialTime;

                MainActivity.this.txtDepthLogger.setText("DepthSlider Move Event"+(MainActivity.this.MoveEventDepthSliderCount++)+"\n"+
                        "PointerCount "+touchEvent.getMotionEvent().getPointerCount()+  " \n " +
                        "D: " + this.DistanceConveredSinceLastDownEvent +" New Scale:" + mPlayer.getScaleX()+" \n " +
                         " New Speed: "+ mPlayer.getSpeed()
                        );
                /*MainActivity.this.txtDepthLogger.setText("Depth CurrX"+touchEvent.getX()+"\n"+
                        "barxrange"+this.getWidth() +"DepthSlider Move Event"+(MainActivity.this.MoveEventDepthSliderCount++)+
                        "PointerID: "+touchEvent.getPointerID()
                        );*/ 



            }
            this.LastPositionTouched=touchEvent.getY();

        }
        if(touchEvent.isActionUp())
        {
            //-----reset speed,scale and stringlength will persist---------------
            MainActivity.this.mPlayer.pressedPlayerActionOnDepth=0; //pressing stopped
            this.isActionDownOccured=false;
            this.initialTime=0;
            this.pressedTime=0;
            this.LastPositionTouched=0;

            MainActivity.this.mPlayer.setSpeed(0);

            //----reset debug variables-----
            MainActivity.this.LongPressEventDepthSliderCount=0;
            MainActivity.this.MoveEventDepthSliderCount=0;

            //MainActivity.this.txtLoggingEventCount.setText("");
            //MainActivity.this.txtLoggingSpriteVariables.setText("");
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

im using onLongPress of GestureListener for Rotation Slider and wrote custom onLOngPress for depth slider, since gesture listener doesnot support MultiTouch. Im performing onLongPress,OnScroll events on player sprite

Comment: Hard to know what's happening without looking at your code, but have you looked at this discussion?  http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/problem-with-two-analog-sticks-t9567.html

Comment: yes i read that link.Its different from my problem , im setting HUD on scene. not children of scene.

Comment: i have added the code, pls see it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution to my problem

I was clearing all previous rotation modifiers on touchevent

I cleared rotation modifiers only on valid events.And it started working.

Perhaps it will be useful for some one else as well.